# Security properties and Cryptography objectives applied in algorithms

Tags: security-definition, non-repudiation

We all know there are five properties of Security. They are:

1. Confidentiality
2. Availability
3. Authorization
4. Integrity and
5. Provenance

As Security and Cryptography are co-related these properties also applicable to Cryptography as well (are't they?). I can understand how a Cryptographic algorithms (e.g. AES)  maintain these properties. But what I don't understand how does the last property "Provenance" is applicable to AES or DES/TripleDES ?

There also four objectives  of Cryptography. They are quite same as the Security properties except for "non-repudiation". How does AES or DES/TripleDES fulfils this objective?

Comment: Each of these goals is achieved via different means. Encryption addresses confidentiality, afaik, but doesn't necessarily take care of integrity, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AES or DES/TripleDES are just primitives. These primitives aide in building the properties of the system you were describing. The 5 properties are that of the system but not a single algorithm. We need a combination of crypto algorithms sometimes to achieve these properties in certain setup.

Few examples,

1. Confidentiality of data-in-transit in a "communication system" is achieved by SSL protocol using combination of symmetric (AES) and asymmetric (RSA etc.) crypto algorithms.
2. Integrity of data-at-rest in a "storage system" is achieved by Hash algorithms
3. Availability of data could be ensured by having good key management systems, to avoid loss/compromise keys which could make data un-available. Ofcourse there are variety of other high available and fault tolerant designs too with crypto primitives.
4. Authorization & Authentication protocols like Kerberos are built using symmetric algos again. More modern access controls could be built using Attribute based encryption etc.
5. Provenance in a cloud storage system is through, "Proofs-of-Storage". Provenance in a cloud compute system is through, "Proofs-of-work". Non-Repudiation in communication protocols are built using digital signatures which in turn could use AES/3-DES internally.

These primitives like AES/DES etc. aide in building much complex security systems. The security properties described are that of the systems but not necessarily the primitives.